# How to Determine Majority Color in a Set of Balls with Conditional Oracle's Responses and Lies in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, logic, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a problem in C where I need to determine the majority color in a set of balls. The challenge includes an Oracle that can lie a fixed number of times. Here are the specifics of my problem:

- **Problem Description**: I have a set of `N` balls (where `N` can be 10, 20, 30, 40), each colored either black or white. There's a guarantee of a majority color. An Oracle can answer if two balls are of the same color, but it's allowed to lie exactly `L` times (where `L` is dependent on `N`, i.e., 1 for 10 balls, 2 for 20, and so on).
- **Querying the Oracle**: I can query the Oracle about any two balls, asking if they are of the same color. The Oracle answers YES or NO, but with the aforementioned lies.
- **Goal**: Determine the color of the majority of the balls.
- **Current Approach**: My current strategy involves querying pairs of balls and tracking the Oracle's responses to deduce the majority. However, this approach seems to falter, especially in scenarios with more balls and lies.
- **Challenges**: The main challenge is to account for the Oracle's lies effectively and determine the majority color with absolute certainty.

I am looking for guidelines on how to approach this problem. Specifically, I'd appreciate insights on:

1. A robust strategy to handle the Oracle's lies and accurately determine the majority.
2. Efficient ways to minimize the number of queries while still reaching a certain conclusion.
3. Any relevant algorithms or data structures that could be particularly useful in this scenario.

**Scoring**

If M queries were asked to Oracle, on correct answer

- M < (L + 1) * N/2, score = 0
- M >= (L + 1) * (N-1), score = 1
- (L + 1) * N/2 <= M < (L + 1) * (N - 1), score = ( (L + 1) * (N - 1) - M )/ 12

Here is a snippet of my current implementation (simplified for clarity):

```c
// Define the maximum number of balls
#define MAX_BALLS 40

// Function to find the group of a ball using recursion and path compression
int findGroup(int ball, int groups[MAX_BALLS])
{
    // If the ball is its own representative, return the ball
    if (groups[ball] == ball)
        return ball;
    
    // Recursively find the representative of the group and perform path compression
    return groups[ball] = findGroup(groups[ball], groups);
}

// Function to union two groups based on their representatives
void unionGroups(int ball1, int ball2, int groups[MAX_BALLS], int sizes[MAX_BALLS])
{
    // Find the representatives of both balls
    int root1 = findGroup(ball1, groups);
    int root2 = findGroup(ball2, groups);

    // If they have different representatives, merge the smaller group into the larger one
    if (root1 != root2)
    {
        if (sizes[root1] < sizes[root2])
        {
            groups[root1] = root2;
            sizes[root2] += sizes[root1];
        }
        else
        {
            groups[root2] = root1;
            sizes[root1] += sizes[root2];
        }
    }
}

// Main function to handle the game logic
void nextQuestion(int n, int plurality, int lies, int color, int exact_lies, int query_size, int query[n][n])
{
    // Initialize arrays to track groups and their sizes
    int groups[MAX_BALLS], sizes[MAX_BALLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        groups[i] = i;  // Each ball starts as its own group
        sizes[i] = 1;   // Each group initially has a size of 1
    }

    // Union groups based on query responses
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (query[i][j] == 1)
                unionGroups(i, j, groups, sizes); // Merge groups if the balls have the same color
        }
    }

    // Find the largest group and its representative
    int largestGroupSize = 0, largestGroupRep = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int groupSize = sizes[findGroup(i, groups)];
        if (groupSize > largestGroupSize)
        {
            largestGroupSize = groupSize;
            largestGroupRep = i;
        }
    }

    // Check if the largest group represents the majority color
    if (largestGroupSize > n / 2 || largestGroupSize + lies > n / 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", largestGroupRep); // Print the representative of the majority color
        return;
    }

    // If not, continue querying to find a contradiction
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (query[i][j] == -1)
            {
                printf("%d %d\n", i, j); // Print the pair of balls that contradicts the majority color
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand this is a complex problem, but I believe there must be a more efficient way to solve it than my current approach. Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is impossible to solve as stated because it is entirely symmetric on color—changing all the black balls for white balls satisfies all the same constraints, and even the oracle’s answers remain unchanged. There is no information that can distinguish white from black. Did you miss something in the problem description? Also, that the oracle is “allowed” to lie “exactly” L times is questionable phrasing. Are its lies less than or equal to L (allowed to be L but not required) or exactly L (it is only allowed to lie exactly L times)?

Comment: If this is an assignment for a school course, has the course covered error-correcting codes? If it is for some online judge/challenge, have you studied error-correcting codes?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, i'm sorry, there is indeed more to say. To solve this problem, you should output the index in the array representing a ball (color) that you believe constitutes the majority. Oracle's Lies Clarification: Given that the oracle can lie up to L times, it's important to note that the oracle is allowed to lie exactly L times only when the number of questions you ask is greater than or equal to L. In other words, the oracle can lie L times if and only if you ask at least L questions. -- It is a challenge on hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/oracle3/problem

Comment: @TermoPollo if you have solved the problem but looking for better efficiency, perhaps the question belongs on Code Review. OTOH, finding an efficient solution is paramount to solving such 'online judge' questions. That's part of the challenge, namely that *you* can solve a problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I appreciate your suggestion to consider Code Review for optimizing efficiency. However, I'd like to clarify that my current solution is tailored to a specific set of 10 balls. I'm not seeking efficiency improvements at this stage. Instead, I'm looking for guidance on how to solve this problem comprehensively for different ball sets (e.g., 10, 20, 30, 40 balls) and lie allowances. Any insights on a scalable approach would be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Additional constraint based on the required function signature: you can only usefully ask once about each distinct pair of balls.

Comment: If you know the maximum number of lies `L` to begin with, can't you query each pair of balls `2L + 1` times and take the majority response as the correct response for that pair?

Comment: @wLui155 I could do this, but that would result in a low final score. M >= (L + 1) * (N-1), score = 1

Comment: @wLui155: You cannot duplicate queries because the problem statement on HackerRank dictates use of a data structure that allows only one answer per pair of balls.